# Why does the keydown event on my target input tag not fire for my function?

Tags: jquery

I have a script block that happily copies a value from a dropdown list and puts it in an input tag. However, the input tag behaviour associated with it. Namely, when I keydown, it filters a column (see DataTables.js). The problem is that despite it copying the value from the dropdown to the input box, it does not fire the keydown event and cause the column to filter. What is wrong with the trigger method below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.dropdownlist').change(function () {
        var e = jQuery.Event('keydown', { which: 9 });
        var controlId = $(this).attr('id');
        var controlText = $('#' + controlId + ' option:selected').text();
        var target = $('input.' + controlId)
        var setTarget = target.val(controlText);
        $(target).trigger(e);
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

datatables.js is available from here: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Where is the `DataTables.js` you talk about :)? Could you provide the markup?

Comment: I downloaded it from here: http://datatables.net/download/

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using `$(target)` to trigger the function? Surely `target.trigger(e)` would be better?